# where to obtain Windows XP-compatible Process Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, process-explorer

Where can I obtain a Windows-XP compatible Process Explorer? the current release of Process Explorer does not run on XP SP3, attempting to executing it just says "Not a valid win32 executable"

Comment: From the error, it's not that it won't run on WInXP, it's that you got the 64-bit version & tried to run it on a 32-bit OS. It's really not that hard to find on google - https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/process-explorer/  but requesting download locations isn't really on topic here.

Comment: @Tetsujin nope i tried to run the 32bit version. funfact, the process explorer [from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is actually just a 32bit extractor/zip-file, containing both 32bit and 64bit process explorer, and when it starts, it checks if the OS is 32bit or 64bit, and extracts the appropriate *real* process explorer, and starts it

Comment: Hmmm… OK. I just downloaded it on a Mac. It just lands as a zip file, that when run simply unpacks the zip, of course. There are 3 versions in there, procexp.exe, procexp64.exe & procexp64a.exe [& an EULA]

Answer (score 3):

Process Explorer version 15.30 is compatible with XP SP3, and is available here http://www.oldversion.com/windows/download/process-explorer-15-30

- The copy served to me by oldversion.com is digitally signed by Microsoft, and the signature is valid, thus this procexp is not tampered.
- I don't know which version is the *last* to support XP, but i know that v15.30 is XP-compatible, and v16.43 is *not* xp-compatible, so XP support was dropped somewhere between v15.30 and 16.43

Answer (score 1):

Your only hope is the Wayback Machine

[SysInternals for XP](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/c/okmkiypRVec?pli=1)

Paul's profile photo
Paul
unread,
Jun 18, 2017, 4:06:39 AM
to
Use the date for the end of WinXP support as a barometer ? [April 8, 2014]

The link for the suite goes back six years, so you can sample
it if you want.

https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

Otherwise XP is dead and use a more modern OS.